# Manual: Mix node update in 3.4 NOT forward compatible?

Tags: node-editor, shader-nodes, documentation

I'm confused by the syntax in this sidebar tip in the 3.6 manual:
[image]

Is this a mistake that should read "*backward* compatible" or "*old* node"? Or is the update to mix nodes for 3.4 only usable in 3.4 and thus mix nodes must be replaced in projects made in 3.4 for all future iterations of Blender 3D?

Further: is it backward compatible if *not* forward compatible?

I assume (if this is an error) that it means "backward compatible" due to the use of "As of" v. 3.4 (suggesting the mix node is broken since 3.4 and no note of an update since), but I don't have any 3.4 files with mix nodes to test this from. Is there any insight on this?

Comment: Maybe you could get some clarification at this link: https://devtalk.blender.org/c/documentation/12